# PHPUNIT_Framework_TestCase not found when running single test

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am trying to use PHPUnit testing with **Laravel 5.2.10**. I have **PHPUnit 5.1.4** installed locally within my project.

When I run:

```
phpunit
```

PHPUnit runs all tests in my `test` directory perfectly.

However, when I run:

```
phpunit tests/unit/testThatFails.php
```

I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUNIT_Framework_TestCase' not found in ...
```

The strange thing is that when I run phpunit it is succesfully running every test in the test directory, including this `testThatFails.php` just fine.

**Why does it break when I try to run just one test?**

**Update:**
Here is my `phpunit.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory>./tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">app/</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

**Update:**
For now, since I am using Laravel, I am **circumventing** this issue by extending `TestCase` rather than `PHPUNIT_Framework_TestCase`, and my tests are able to run as expected. However, this is just a **circumvention** and not a **solution**. (It is also strange to me that this works given the fact that `TestCase` itself does ultimately extend from `PHPUNIT_Framework_TestCase`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The message says `PHPUNIT_Framework_TestCase`, but the class is actually called `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`. Now here is the tricky thing

- Class names in PHP are case insensitive, that's why it works when you run the whole test suite and the class is already loaded. **BUT**
- The autoloader is case sensitive, because your file system is case sensitive and it cannot guess the correct case.

So when you run the test separately, the class `PHPUNIT_Framework_TestCase` is not loaded before your test case file is included and the autoloader will look for a file `PHPUNIT/Framework/TestCase.php` instead of `PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php`. This file does not exist and you receive the "class not found" error.

#### Solution

Replace

```
class TestThatFails extends PHPUNIT_Framework_TestCase
```

with

```
class TestThatFails extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
```

Comment: ahhh.... excellent answer. I didn't even realize the difference in case until you pointed it out. Thanks for the clear explanation too. Everything is green now :)

Answer (score 2):

PHPUnit loads the configuration file `phpunit.xml` (see [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/phpunit.xml)) that actually holds the info about the bootstrap file

```
...
bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
...
```

It is the `bootstrap.php` that loads the `autoloader` thus making all of those classes available in your app.

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

The `autoload.php`, probably, is not included in the `testThatFails.php`. The `autoload php` loads the `PHPUNIT_Framework_TestCase` along with other files/classes that may be relevant to this case (some other unit test classes, etc.). IMHO the best way, other than including it in the `phpunit.xml`, is to include the bootstrap file as an argument in command

```
phpunit --bootstrap bootstrap/autoload.php testThatFails.php
```

Comment: can you elaborate as to why the classes are being loaded when I run `phpunit` but not when I try to run a specific test?

Comment: The command you suggest is for running all tests. I can already successfully run all tests. For some reason it is when I try and single out a single test that the class is not able to be resolved. I have updated the question to include my `phpunit.xml` file, maybe there is an explanation hidden somewhere in there?

Comment: @tam you can specify the test you would like to run right after the bootstrap file. See my updated answer.

Comment: ah I see I thought that was probably an option, thanks. The trouble is, I still get the same error! :(

Comment: @tam what is the content of `bootstrap/autoload.php` ?